# Integrating Search-SphinxsearchBundle into Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I'm using Symfony-standard,
I have installed [Search-SphinxsearchBundle](http://knpbundles.com/timewasted/Search-SphinxsearchBundle)

I was assuming, i would use it's services in controller, to fetch documentation in my **app/Resources/docs**, where there's index.srt, I need to know how to direct the bundle to search from my folder.

I want to use it to query my index.srt documentations in app/Resources/docs.
**I'm stuck on app/config/config.yml**

```
sphinxsearch:
    indexes:
        - name: books
          index:
              - %sphinxsearch_index_books%
          field_weights:
              label: 10
              content: 5
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException' 
with message 'You have requested a non-existent parameter "sphinxsearch_index_pages".' 
in /usr/local/dev/hris/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:108 Stack trace: 
#0 /usr/local/dev/hris/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php(234): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag->get('sphinxsearch_in...') 
#1 /usr/local/dev/hris/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php(205): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag->resolveString('%sphinxsearch_i...', Array) 
#2 /usr/local/dev/hris/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php(195): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag->resolveValue('%sphinxsearch_i...', Array) 
#3 /usr/local/dev/hris/vendo in /usr/local/dev/hris/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php on line 108
```

Comment: there seems to be come confusion here. There are two products called sphinx (well there are more!) but here thinking of Sphinx Python based Documentation generator) and SphinxSearch (a database full-text query engine). THe bundle you found appears to be for SPhinxSearch, but I think the index.irt is from python-sphinx. SO you need to find a bundle for Python-Sphinx NOT for SphinxSearch

Comment: That index.srt is the index of the rest of my documentation(all the docs are written in reStructuredText). I need a php bundle to parse the documentation.

Comment: Yes, so you are looking for something that works with python-sphinx documentation generators, NOT something for SphinxSearch (like Search-SphinxsearchBundle is)